# Toggle an animation over an element of a grid and fadein/out the other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am experimenting with a tile-like layout for my site with which the user can interact. Each box is a button used to select a product, and upon selection of a product, the other boxes fade out and are hidden. This effect is toggle-able.

I have slightly modified the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhL8cLcm/) that I found online, and it comes very close the desired result.

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  $('.box').not(this).fadeToggle(250);
});
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 63px;
  background-color: #52c6ec;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 37px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box1">Box 1</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">Box 2</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">Box 3</div>
<div class="box" id="box4">Box 4</div>
<div class="box" id="box5">Box 5</div>
<div class="box" id="box6">Box 6</div>
<div class="box" id="box7">Box 7</div>
<div class="box" id="box8">Box 8</div>
<div class="box" id="box9">Box 9</div>
<div class="box" id="box10">Box 10</div>
<div class="box" id="box11">Box 11</div>
<div class="box" id="box12">Box 12</div>
<div class="box" id="box13">Box 13</div>
<div class="box" id="box14">Box 14</div>
<div class="box" id="box15">Box 15</div>
<div class="box" id="box16">Box 16</div>
<div class="box" id="box17">Box 17</div>
<div class="box" id="box18">Box 18</div>
<div class="box" id="box19">Box 19</div>
<div class="box" id="box20">Box 20</div>
```

The only thing I want to do is to have the selected item transition (via animation) to the top-left, rather than just appearing there. Preferably also during the fading of the other boxes.

Because I'm using floats here, I cannot figure out how to animate these, since they don't have any numeric properties.

Ideas for a jQuery solution? Thanks.

Comment: `float` cannot be animated or transitioned. You might need to rethink. Pretty much adjusting positiioning is done by...erm, positioning everything and adjusting *all* the positioning by JS.

Comment: do you need a single animation to top left? or also the opposite movement?

Comment: @fcalderan I need a single element to animate to the top left on selection, but the reverse animation when it's unselected.

Comment: Not sure why someone labeled this as a question asking for an off-topic resource. jQuery is obviously on-topic.

Comment: Not sure but *"Ideas for a jQuery solution?"* **sounds** like a request for a plug-in...which is off-topic. If that's *not* what it is then it breaks down to a *give me teh codez* question which is equally off-topic. At least that's *my* interpretation.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I've already provided a code and mention I cannot figure out how to animate them. If I wanted a plugin I would've provided neither.

Comment: I'm just saying the way it *appears* as a possible reason for the CV. What is left is *effectively* a code request. Just sayin. I **up**voted the question.

Comment: Fair enough @Paulie_D, I guess it's all a matter of perspective anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt in *vanilla JS* (tested on Chrome and Firefox)
Basically it works only with CSS transitions over the `transform` property for the selected element and over the `opacity` for all the other elements. The fadeOut/In runs while the selected element is moving as you specified.

> [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzabPR?editors=0110)

---

**CSS**

```
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div {
   background: #a0c6df;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 2px #8fa0c6 dashed;
   margin: 10px;
   opacity: 1;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: all 1s;
}

main.fadeout div:not(.current) {
   opacity: 0;
   cursor: default;
}
```

**JS**

```
var main = document.querySelector('main');
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('main div');
var animationIsRunning = false;

var getBoxPosition = function() {
  [].forEach.call(boxes, function(b) {
     var gBCR = b.getBoundingClientRect();
     b.dataset.top = gBCR.top;
     b.dataset.left = gBCR.left;
  }); 
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var dc;
    getBoxPosition();
    if (dc = main.querySelector('div.current')) {
       main.classList.remove('fadeout');
       dc.classList.remove('current');
       dc.style.transform = 'translate(0,0)';
    }
});

main.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
   var b    = evt.target,
       left = 0, 
       top  = 0;

   /* listen to the div click event only */
   if (b.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'div') { return false; }

   /* don't listen if there's a current element and user clicked 
      over a hidden div */
   if (
       main.querySelector('.current') &&
       !b.classList.contains('current')
   ) { return false; }

   /* only if another animation is not running... */
   if (!animationIsRunning) {
       animationIsRunning = true;

       b.classList.toggle('current');
       main.classList.toggle('fadeout');

       if (b.classList.contains('current')) {
          left = b.dataset.left;
          top  = b.dataset.top;
       }

       b.style.transform = 'translate(-'+ left +'px, -'+ top +'px)';
   }
});

main.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  animationIsRunning = false;
});


getBoxPosition();
```

Comment: Nice! How would I add the fading(in or out) *during* each animation?

Comment: It doesn't seem to return to its' original position though. :/ Vanilla JS is a big plus though. If you can do this in vanilla http://jsfiddle.net/wefts276/3/ it would be fantastic! This is an update with desired behavior (except some weird delay on the unselect click)

Comment: Really!? Works fine for me. What's bugging out for you?

Comment: I used Chrome when coding that example. For me, your codepen doesnt have the selected item return when you click on it the 2nd time.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```js
var t, l, loctop, locleft;

$('.box').click(function() {
  
  var e = $(this);
  
  if( $('.box').not(this).is(':visible') )
  {
    t = e.position().top + 'px';
    l = e.position().left + 'px';
    loctop = locleft = 0;
    $(this).css( {position: 'fixed', top:t, left:l} );
    $('.box').not(this).fadeToggle(550, function(){
      $(e).animate({ 
          top: loctop,
          left: locleft
        }, 800, function(){
        $(this).stop(true, true);
      });
    });
  }
  else
  {
    loctop = parseInt(t);
    locleft = parseInt(l);
    $(e).animate({ 
          top: loctop,
          left: locleft
        }, 800, function(){
      $('.box').not(this).fadeIn(550, function(){
        $(e).css( {position: 'relative', top:'', left:''} );
      });
    });
  }
  
});
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 63px;
  background-color: #52c6ec;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 37px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box1">Box 1</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">Box 2</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">Box 3</div>
<div class="box" id="box4">Box 4</div>
<div class="box" id="box5">Box 5</div>
<div class="box" id="box6">Box 6</div>
<div class="box" id="box7">Box 7</div>
<div class="box" id="box8">Box 8</div>
<div class="box" id="box9">Box 9</div>
<div class="box" id="box10">Box 10</div>
<div class="box" id="box11">Box 11</div>
<div class="box" id="box12">Box 12</div>
<div class="box" id="box13">Box 13</div>
<div class="box" id="box14">Box 14</div>
<div class="box" id="box15">Box 15</div>
<div class="box" id="box16">Box 16</div>
<div class="box" id="box17">Box 17</div>
<div class="box" id="box18">Box 18</div>
<div class="box" id="box19">Box 19</div>
<div class="box" id="box20">Box 20</div>
```

Comment: Only issue here (and I like what you have so far) is that it's doesn't animate back to the old position.

Comment: Very close! As Paulie_D said, I'd like it to animate back as well.

Comment: @Paulie_D and Chris, Please check the new update. It can go back to it's original position now.

Comment: Nice! I was also working on a variation of your first answer. Similar behaviour but mine also inserts a dummy element behind the selected element so that 2 items never overlap. Check http://jsfiddle.net/wefts276/3/. Do you know why there is a delay on the unselect though? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I added [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) function of jQuery to stop the animation. Because I noticed that it animates all elements with `box` class. This is the exact line I added. `$(this).stop(true, true);`. Check it out, I modified your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wefts276/5/) a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this awesome plugin (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) from David Desandro

You can find an exemple on codepen here :

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nFrte

An exemple from isotope blog :

```js
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

var $notifElem;

$( document ).ready( function() {

  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 100
    }
  });

  $grid.on( 'layoutComplete', function( event, laidOutItems ) {
    console.log( 'layoutComplete with ' + laidOutItems.length + ' items' );
  });

  $grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item', function() {
    // change size of item by toggling gigante class
    $( this ).toggleClass('grid-item--gigante');
    $grid.isotope('layout');
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0D8;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
}

.grid-item--width2 { width: 200px; }
.grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }

.grid-item:hover {
  background: #8CF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-item--gigante {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #F80;
}

.notification {
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.2/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - layoutComplete</h1>

<p>Open Developer Console to view event logs.</p>

<p>Click item to toggle size</p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>

<div class="notification"></div>
```

Comment: While this is surely a great plugin, I'm only looking for a pure jQuery solution at this point. If no such solution exists, I may have to resort to something like you're suggesting. But for the moment it's not on the table. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @chris look at the plugin code, and extract what you need

Answer (score 0):

> **Hope this will be very useful for you.** I have created full working
>   code You can use this.

```js
var a=0;
$('.box').click(function() {
  if(a==0){
  var position = $(this).position();
$( "this" ).text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
  $(this).css({
    "position":"absolute",
    "left":position.left,
    "top":position.top
    
  })
  $('.box').not(this).fadeOut(250);
  $(this).animate({
  "left":"0px",
    "top":"0px"
  }, 1000);
    a=1;
    }
  else{
    $('.box').not(this).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).css({"position":"static"});
    a=0;
  
  }
  
});
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 63px;
  background-color: #52c6ec;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 37px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box1">Box 1</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">Box 2</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">Box 3</div>
<div class="box" id="box4">Box 4</div>
<div class="box" id="box5">Box 5</div>
<div class="box" id="box6">Box 6</div>
<div class="box" id="box7">Box 7</div>
<div class="box" id="box8">Box 8</div>
<div class="box" id="box9">Box 9</div>
<div class="box" id="box10">Box 10</div>
<div class="box" id="box11">Box 11</div>
<div class="box" id="box12">Box 12</div>
<div class="box" id="box13">Box 13</div>
<div class="box" id="box14">Box 14</div>
<div class="box" id="box15">Box 15</div>
<div class="box" id="box16">Box 16</div>
<div class="box" id="box17">Box 17</div>
<div class="box" id="box18">Box 18</div>
<div class="box" id="box19">Box 19</div>
<div class="box" id="box20">Box 20</div>
```

Comment: Close, but it doesn't *animate back* to original position.